# Want to remove square brackets from json file with script python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file, and I want to remove all fields after the square bracket with scripts in Python.

My JSON file is this:

```json
    {
  "Employees": [
    {
      "userId": "krish",
      "jobTitle": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Krish",
      "lastName": "Lee",
      "employeeCode": "E1",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "123456",
      "emailAddress": "krish.lee@learningcontainer.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": "devid",
      "jobTitle": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Devid",
      "lastName": "Rome",
      "employeeCode": "E2",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "1111111",
      "emailAddress": "devid.rome@learningcontainer.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": "tin",
      "jobTitle": "Program Directory",
      "firstName": "tin",
      "lastName": "jonson",
      "employeeCode": "E3",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "2222222",
      "emailAddress": "tin.jonson@learningcontainer.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

My script is this:

```py
import json
import re

with open('data.json')as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in data:
        re.sub(" *\[.*\] *"," ",item)

with open('new_data.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(item, f)
```

I expect this:

```json
{
  "Employees": 
}
```

but I receive this:

```
"Employees"
```

Tell me why it takes off the braces, and come and solve this problem.

Comment: `{ "Employees": }` isn't valid anything.

Comment: `re.sub(" *\[.*\] *"," ",item)` doesn't serve any purpose if you do not capture the return value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSON is a serialization of a data structure and has no canonical format. This means that doing any kind of text matching or regular expressions on it is a very bad idea and just asking for trouble.

The proper way to do is to use a JSON parser to convert it into objects, then synthesize whatever output you want based on object data.

In your case, the parsed object will be a dictionary with a single key which you can obtain for example like this:

```
print("{{\n  \"{0}\":\n}}".format(list(json.load(f).keys())[0]))
```

Result:

```
{
  "Employees":
}
```

For whatever is worth, this is not a valid JSON so I'm not sure why you need it.